# How to save both results of the MAP method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get an array and want objects with different TPAs (Item.Type) add to different components. But in the end I only get the last. How to do what would both ITEM be saved in the component and did not flip each other?

```
{
  list.map((item) => (
    <div>{item.type == 1 ? <DetailedOne item={item} /> : ""}</div>
  ));
}
{
  list.map((item) => (
    <div>{item.type == 2 ? <DetailedTwo item={item} /> : ""}</div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Do you need two `map()` method calls on the same array? Maybe an `if-else` statement can help achieve the desired result?

Comment: I need to get both results in different methods. In the case of if else, I will receive only one result

Comment: What exactly does *"I only get the last"* mean? What does *"flip each other"* mean? There is nothing technically wrong with what is shown but it's not clear why you need 2 map and not use if/else in one unless you need the two types grouped together. You really haven't explained expected behavior in detail. See [ask]

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I think it as simple as using `find` to find both items from the list and passing those to their components:

```
const [item1, item2] = useMemo(() => {
  const item1 = list.find((item) => item.type === 1)
  const item2 = list.find((item) => item.type === 2)
  return [item1, item2]
}, [list])

// JSX
<DetailedOne item={item1} />
<DetailedTwo item={item2} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to combine the results from both `map()` calls.

Furthermore, I would recommend using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) because you are now creating empty `<div>`s that look like nothing but pollution to me.

Code:

```
{
  list.filter(item.type == 1).map((item) => (
    <div><DetailedOne item={item}</div>
  )).concat(
    list.filter(item.type == 2).map((item) => (
    <div><DetailedTwo item={item}</div>
    ))
  );
}
```